# Ayuda con R bucle for

Tags: r, bucle-for, condiciones

Tengo el siguiente problema

Sea X1 , . . . , Xn una muestra aleatoria de una población con distribución N(μ,σ^2).

Si σ^2 es desconocida. Encuentre el valor mínimo de n que garantice que, con
probabilidad 0.90, el intervalo del 95 % de confianza para μ tendrá longitud no
mayor que σ/4.

Para lo cual escribí el siguiente código:

```
    for(n in 1:1000){
  z <- 64*qchisq(0.9, n-1)*qt(0.975, n-1)^2
  if((n*(n-1))>=z)
  print(n)
  break
}
```

O sea con un bucle for recorror las n y con un if pongo la condición para encontrar a la indicada, pero al momento de correrlo me lanza el error

```
Warning message: NaNs produced
Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>
```

¿me pide un booleano?, ¿en donde debería ir?

Comment: Bienvenido Jorge Salvador Martnez Villafa a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se genera cuando utilizas las función `qt()`, esta función tiene los parametros: `p, df, ncp, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)`, pero se tiene que cumplir que `df>0`. Pero cuando generas el `for`empezando en 1, `z` es igual a Nan, por lo que al tener pasar al `ìf()` te marca el error por comparar un Nan. Entonces te recomiendo que inicialices el 'for()' en 2 para que puedas evaluar tu función de 'z' o igual plantea de otra forma la resolución del problema original.

```
for(n in  2:1000){
  z <- 64*qchisq(0.9, n-1)*qt(0.975, n-1)^2
  print(n)
  if((n*(n-1))>=z)
    print(n)
    break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de `qt()` el parámetro `df` dice:

> degrees of freedom (> 0, maybe non-integer). df = Inf is allowed.

Es decir, los grados de libertad, siempre son valores mayores 0 hasta `Inf`, por lo que la primer iteración del ciclo es la que está fallando, es decir:

```
n <- 1
qt(0.975, n - 1) # df = 0
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In qt(0.975, n - 1) : NaNs produced
```

El retorno no numérico hace que toda la clausula termine siendo `NaN` y finalmente produce el error cuando haces la comparación lógica `if((n*(n-1))>=z)`. El error es básicamente que el `if()`  espera un valor lógico, pero lo estás alimentando con un `NaN`.

Como solucionar esto, escapa un poco a mi limitado conocimiento estadístico, como programador puedo decirte: a) evitar comenzar desde 1, `for(n in 2:1000)` o bien b) considerar particularmente el calculo cuando `n=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no existe el valor Z, pon Z= -64*qchisq(0.9, n-1)*qt(0.975, n-1)^2 , que creo q deseas obtener y comparar con n. eso o Z -= 64*qchisq(0.9, n-1)*qt(0.975, n-1)^2 que estarias restando del anterior valor de z.